# копирование файла Ubuntu c http из консоли SSH

Tags: ubuntu

Как из консоли Ubuntu 16.04 скопировать файл, расположенный по адресу http://site.ru/1.zip в локальный каталог /backup/1.zip ?

Comment: `wget -O /backup/1.zip http://site.ru/1.zip`

Comment: Или `curl` например

Comment: `aria2c --dir=/backup http://site.ru/1.zip`

Comment: andreymal, NewView, don Rumata: ну так а ответ-то кто будет писать? пушкин, что ли? так он умер уже.